# ionic v3 see scss file line in main.css file

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

Any way to see the file name in the main.css file?

Something like this

```
/* line 269, /Users/mypc/Desktop/proyectos/myapp/src/client/lib/ionic/scss/_tabs.scss */
 ion-tabs.tabs-color-active-assertive .tab-item {
     color: #444; 
 }
```

I see that this tab-item is in the _tabs.scss file but with ionic v3 using this
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts
but.. I only see

```
ion-tabs.tabs-color-active-assertive .tab-item {
     color: #444; 
 }
```

So it's so hard to know in which file/line is that css class.

Comment: I think there is noway to do it. A walk around is each scss file have a root css selector. You should write all your css inside it and follow it you will find out the file of the css. I.e `some-page div{display: none}` meaning the css come from `some-page.scss`